# "It’s the height of the season"?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context, dummy-it

The question is from the [transcript](http://www.scientificamerican.com/podcast/episode.cfm?id=early-20th-century-botanist-gave-us-11-06-17) of a podcast:

> Mmmm, blueberries. *It’s the height of the season*, and I’ve been tossing a handful onto cereal, into pancakes or just straight into my mouth.

I don't understand what does the sentence "It's the height of the season" mean.

- What does "it" refer to? Does it indicate "blueberries"?
- What does "the height of the season" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The season** is the yearly period in which a certain activity is best performed for whatever reason, usually something that depends on climate and natural seasons. Cf. the *hunting season*, the *asparagus season*. The blueberry season is when blueberries are ripe for the picking.

**The height of the season** is the very best point within this period to pick blueberries, probably because there are the most, or they taste best.

**It** is more or less a dummy subject; you could say it means "this time", just as in *it is sunny in London*.

Answer (score 1):

"**Now** is the height of the blueberry season, when they are common and tasty."

(actually the season's nearly over by now: go and pick blueberries, rather than surfing the net).

Comment: in the northeastern USA the blueberry season is July and early August, depending on location. It's peak strawberry season right now.