# What does "deepest summer" mean?

Tags: word-usage

I am new to this English stack exchange, I asked this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/in-the-last-scene-of-the-movie-a-clockwork-orange-by-stanley-kubrick?noredirect=1#comment13667_12100) on the movie stack exchange

Though it was a question from a movie it's also related to English Language. I will be simply pleased and delighted if anyone could help me to understand. Thank you

Comment: The middle of the summer. Depends on country. July/August in most cases

Comment: I think of it as the time of summer when spring is just a memory, and autumn is not yet looming. As a child, it would have been halfway between the last day of school and the first day of the next school year.

Comment: Strangely, same meaning as 'the height of summer': see http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30407/8019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the middle of July/August in the northern hemisphere, or around Xmas in for example Cape Town when the sky looks like this when we look up

[image: Azure]

Comment: lightest  summer?

Comment: (Taxi Driver - ignore that quip. As the other comments etc say, it's _deep_ in the sense _furthest from the surface / start and finish_, with a hint of luxuriant foliage.)

Comment: Your comment says "July/August *in most cases*" and in your answer you repeat "July/August". But that applies only in the Northern Hemisphere. I dispute "in most cases" - there are countries in the Southern hemisphere with summer in December/January!

Comment: Right. Corrected. However I feel deep summer is more a northern thing :)

Comment: The sky always looks like that.

Comment: Then you have never been to Holland ;))

Comment: BTW, What does the sky look like at *other times*?

Comment: Like this: http://www.ocshades.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Winter-Snow-32.jpg - much more turquoise ;)

Comment: @tchrist My wife Catherine and I passed through your neck of the woods on a wonderful tour of the SW US NPs last year. On one occasion **it rained heavily.** At Mt Rushmore NM. For at least 60 seconds.